# rspec: undefined method 'has_conent?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

Hello I am having an issue with railstutorial.

I have the test file `features/static_pages_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do
  describe "Home page" do
    it "Should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      page.should have_conent('Sample App')
    end
  end
end
```

when I run `bundle exec rspec spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb`

I get the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) Static pages Home page Should have the content 'Sample App'
     Failure/Error: page.should have_conent('Sample App')
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_conent?' for #<Capybara::Session>
     # ./spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.05262 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb:6 # Static pages Home page Should have the content 'Sample App'

Randomized with seed 49777
```

I tried to add in the `spec_helper.rb` `config.include Capybara::DSL` but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Thanks I didnt saw this stupid error

Comment: it happens :)  if it helped, please check the answer so it's out of the 'unanswered' queue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a typo:

```
page.should have_conent('Sample App')
```

should be

```
page.should have_content('Sample App')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo. You are missing a `t` in your content

```
page.should have_content('Sample App')
```